# React Update State with Array/Objects

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React, and I'm building my first project.
In my project, I'm coding a "library" with an array filled with different books.

```
const initialBooks = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'JavaScript',
    author: 'Author1',
    isbn: '978-3836286299',
    rating: 5,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'CodeFaster',
    author: 'Author2',
    isbn: '978-0132350884',
    rating: 3,
  }
];
```

In my component I would like to set up a state for the books:

```
  const [books, setBooks] = useState(initialBooks);
```

Now I want to update the rating for a selected book.

```
  function handleRate(id, rating) {
    setBooks((prevState) => {
      let b = prevState;
      let selectedBook = b.find((book) => book.id === id);
      selectedBook.rating = rating;
      return b;
    });
  }
```

When I select a book and set a new rating, the array will be modified, but I can't see anything. Can somebody tell me why this doesn't work? I think that I misunderstood something or that something is not clear to me.

Thanks!

Comment: State should not be modified directly. If you search for "react don't modify state directly" or similar you'll get to what you need 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a copy of an array before modifying:
`let b = [...prevState];`